# Trying to port Visual Studio solution to Linux, is there anyway to g++ a whole directory recursively?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, port

Trying to port Visual Studio solution to Linux, is there anyway to g++ a whole directory recursively?

There are lots of files to compile and before making a clean makefile I'd like to simply compile once and see what it gives...

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870533/where-can-i-find-a-tool-to-convert-a-vs-solution-to-a-gcc-makefile

Answer (score 2):

You can try using find like below:

```
find . -name *.cpp -exec g++ -c {}\;
```

It's also easy to create a wildcard make file do to the compile and linking for you:

```
CC = g++
COMPILE = $(CC) -c
OBJF := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))

all: prog

prog: $(OBJF)
      $(CC) -o prog $(OBJF)

%.o: %.cpp
      $(COMPILE) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: You may like to make target "all" phony.